# what regular expression to extract between bracket?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I using regular expression to extract word between '[' and ']'.

for example,
if source is `Select [dataset\XYIblqF13F79A4163724A73.png] to [colorful]`
the output I want is `dataset\XYIblqF13F79A4163724A73.png` and `colorful` .

I tried with `^\[.\]$` but it doesn't work.

Can I get some idea?

Comment: if your using javascript then you can use split function

Comment: @Wajid thanks for comment but I'm using `re` module with python

Answer (score 0):

I tried `\[(.*?)\]` and it works well.